# A inequality from the distances of two sets.

Tags: metric-spaces

> $\textbf{Definition}$ : Let $(X,d)$ a metric space, $a\in X$ and $A,B\subseteq X$.
>
> The distance from $x$ to set $A$ is the set :
> $$ d(x,A)= inf\{ d(x,a);a \in A\} $$
> And the distance from $A$ to $B$ is the set :
> $$ d(A,B)=inf\{d(a,b) \vert a\in A,b\in B \}$$

Let $X$ a metric space and $A,B \subseteq X$. Prove that for $x \in X$ :

$$ d(A,B) \leq d(x,A)+d(x,B) $$

Mi proof :

Let suppose $d(A,B)> d(x,A)+d(x,B) $ then $d(A,B)-d(x,A)>d(x,B)$ so by the definition of $d(x,B)$ exists
$b\in B$ such that

$$ d(x,b)<d(A,B)-d(x,A) \implies d(x,A)<d(A,B)-d(x,b) $$

Again by the definition of $d(x,A)$ exists $a\in A$ such that

$$ d(x,a)< d(A,B)-d(x,b) \implies d(a,b) \leq d(a,x)+d(x,b) < d(A,B) $$

A contradiction so $$ d(A,B) \leq d(x,A)+d(x,B) $$

Mi proof is right?

Comment: Please, define what you mean by $d(x,A)$, $d(A,B)$, since there are different notions. It appears that you are using $d(A,B)=inf d(a,b)$ where $inf$ is taken over all pairs $(a,b)\in A\itimes B$.

Comment: $d(x,A)= inf\{ d(x,a), a \in A \}$ and $d(A,B)= inf \{ d(a,b); a \in A, b \in B \} $

Comment: You should edit your question by adding these definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is correct.

[30 characters]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1180419)

Comment: @AlanMuniz, in fact it does. The question was: "Is my proof correct?". And that is a valid answer to it.